# GestureDetector (Exception caught by gesture)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to make a todo app. I create objects in card view, but when I press the delete icon on them when I first start the application, they do not delete the objects, they act as if I clicked the card and it gives this error. In the later ones, only the short text in red.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: allTodo.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      onTap: () {
                        if (allTodo[index].ID == null) {
                          print("id is null, cant perform add operation");
                          return;
                        }
                        _controllerTitle.text = allTodo[index].title;
                        clickedTodoID = allTodo[index].ID!;
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      title: Text(allTodo[index].title),
                      trailing: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          if (allTodo[index].ID != null) {
                            _deleteTodo(allTodo[index].ID!, index);
                             setState(() {});
                          } else {
                            print("id is null, cant perform Delete operation");
                          }
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

---

**todo.dart**

```
class Todo {
  int? ID;
  late String title;

  Todo(this.title);
  Todo.withId(this.ID, this.title);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["ID"] = ID;
    map["title"] = title;
    return map;
  }

  Todo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    this.ID = map["ID"];
    this.title = map["title"];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `allTodo[index].ID` is null here.

Try

```dart
onTap: () {
  if (allTodo[index].ID == null) {
    return;
  }
  setState(() {
    _controllerTitle.text = allTodo[index].title;
    clickedTodoID = allTodo[index].ID!;
  });
},
```

Use this snippet

```dart
return Card(
  child: ListTile(
    onTap: () {
      if (allTodo[index].ID == null) {
        print("id is null, cant perform add operation");
        return;
      }

      _controllerTitle.text = allTodo[index].title;
      clickedTodoID = allTodo[index].ID!;
      setState(() {});
    },
    title: Text(allTodo[index].title),
    trailing: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (allTodo[index].ID != null) {
          _deleteTodo(allTodo[index].ID!, index);
          setState(() {});
        } else {
          print("id is null, cant perform Delete operation");
        }
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.delete),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: error occurred again [error](https://i.imgur.com/iVu9QBq.png) .

Comment: Did you return on cases as I included.  Can you include full widget that will reproduce the same issue, More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [image](https://i.imgur.com/aXfAL8U.png)

Comment: put setState at the end ,do for trailing too, if doesnt work, consider including full widget

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what you mean

Comment: Try update snippet part, replace your card with it

Comment: This just erased the contents of the cards, and when you deleted one, it erased them all. [image](https://i.imgur.com/Tnyw6CQ.png)

Comment: Oh I commented tittle, try now

Comment: also newly created items spawn as empty

Comment: error in its current state etc. none, but no function in delete buttons so delete doesn't work

Comment: Then it seems  you dont have any id, you can debug/print

Comment: nothing came up in debugging

Comment: means you are nothing as ID, are you able to get it ? Check the console for and you will get print state if it is null  from update snippet

Comment: I use translation because my English is poor, so I can't fully understand what you are saying. Can you write how I can do this in the answer section?

Comment: Replace your card widget with current `Card` snippet. Then run your app. Also check the console while tapping on Card

Comment: yes i did these, when i press the card, the text "id is null, cant perform add operation" appears in the console, when i press the delete key, the text "id is null, cant perform Delete operation" appears in the console

Comment: issue is coming from different part, most likely top level,

Comment: What do you mean by top level?

Comment: Could the problem be related to the id being nullable? I put the part I mentioned at the bottom of the question section.

Comment: You may not have seen it, I wanted to write it again. I would be very happy if you could help.

Comment: Ok let check again, I think it issue because of using `!`, But I've check on first place, Can you include full widget that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: I have attached the entire file to the bottom of the question.

Comment: did i get it wrong :|

Comment: Was that another part you wanted me to add?